# PHP - error: 'Trying to get property of non-object' when trying to assign variables with shopping cart array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a following array:

```
    `print_r($cart);`
```

> Array ( [eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [qty]
>   => 3 
>       [price] => 89.19 [name] => null [rowid] => eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 
>       [subtotal] => 267.57 ) )

yet I can't figure out a way to read individual rows from it.

the standard way:

```
foreach ($cart as $item):
    $id = $item->id;
    <...>
```

gives me that error mentioned in the title...

How do I read it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access it as an object (`->`) when it's an array. What you want to do is this:

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $item):
    $id = $item['id'];
endforeach;
```

---

**Notes**

- Arrays are accessed like this: `variable[array_index]`
- While objects are accessed like this: `variable->object_index`